# Unable to print image and text side by side when text is dynamically imported in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

While displaying image and text side by side, the image is moving behind the card-header.

However, if the text printed statically like `<div class="card-header"> Sample` in place of `<div class="card-header" id="business">` there are no issues.

Please advise. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
          {
  var business = "Sample";
      document.getElementById('business').innerHTML = business;
});
```

```css
.card-header {
 padding: .40rem 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #01233F;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
  color: #fff;
}


.card-body {
 padding: .40rem 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-5 mb-3">
    <div class="card h-90 text-left">
    <div class="card-body custom-cards">
    <h4><div class="card-header" id="business"> <img alt="Green" align="right" src="http://nautilus.baruch.sc.edu/twiki_dmcc/pub/Main/ObsCatalog/green_operational_icon.png" width="32" height="32"></div></h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It isn't being hidden, it's being cleared. You set innerHTML to a new value, so the old gets removed.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Any quick tip, to resolve this issue?

Comment: Use DOM manipulation methods like [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), [insertAdjacentText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText)

Comment: `document.getElementById('business').innerHTML += business;` add the + is another option to add onto the above.

Comment: @NickTimmer and PatrickEvans - much thanks fellas. I was hustling around playing with the div :)